# Using Split method or Regex to separate string

Tags: python, regex, string, web-scraping, split

In my project I am webscrapping UFC website to gather to the total wins, total losses, and total draws of each UFC athlete.

This is part of my code, as I wish to strip the total wins, total losses, and total draws separately:

```
import re
record = "10-7-3 (W-L-D)" #W = wins, L= Loss, D= Draws
char = "-"
record+="-"
totalwins = ""
totalloss = ""
totaldraws = ""


correctRecord = re.findall('\[[^\]]*\]|\([^\)]*\)|\"[^\"]*\"|\S+',record)[0]

print("The correct record per fighter is:", correctRecord)

totaldash = 0
for i in range(len(correctRecord)):
    if(record[i] == char):
    
        totaldash+=1
   
   
        if totaldash == 1:
            print("The total wins", totalwins)
            totalwins =""
        elif totaldash ==2:
       
            print("The total losses ", totalwins)
       
            totalwins=""
       
        elif totaldash ==3:
       
            print("The total draws ", totalwins)
   
   
    elif (correctRecord[i] !=char):
        totalwins +=correctRecord[i]
```

The result is the following:

```
   
   The correct record per fighter is: 10-7-3
   The total wins 10
   The total losses  7
```

The problem is, I am unable to spew out the total draws. I also tried using the strip method with no avail:

```
correctRecord= str(record.split(separator, 1)[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import re

record = "10-7-3 (W-L-D)"

wins, loss, draw = map(int, re.findall(r"\d+", record))

print(f"{wins=} {loss=} {draw=}")
```

Prints:

```
wins=10 loss=7 draw=3
```

Answer (score 1):

Something a little more complicated which will work in the event the data is in a different order:

```py
import re

record = "10-3-7 (W-D-L)"
values = re.findall(r'\d+|[WDL]', record)
vdict = dict(zip(values[3:], values[:3]))
print(f'wins={vdict["W"]}, losses={vdict["L"]}, draws={vdict["D"]}')
```

Output:

```
wins=10, losses=7, draws=3
```